# NIntegrate seems to not recognize multiplication of Piecewise function and f[t_]:= function, Why?

Tags: functions, numerical-integration, piecewise, assignment, function-construction

Considering inputs:

```
vti={0, 1.5, 2.4, 5.0675, 7.735, 10};
Vscc=1.5; PSA=0.025; f=0.6; m=10;
```

I defined a function "pwtemp2", using "FC1" and "FC2":

```
    FC1[t_] := Count[vti, x_ /; (t - Vscc) \[LessSlantEqual] x < t];
    FC2[t_] := Count[vti, x_ /; (t - f Vscc) \[LessSlantEqual] x < t];

pwtemp2[t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{PSA^FC1[t], 
     Vscc \[LessSlantEqual] t < 2 Vscc}, {PSA^FC2[t], 
     2 Vscc \[LessSlantEqual] t < m}}];
```

When I Plot pwtemp2, its OK:

```
Plot[pwtemp2[t], {t, 0, m}, PlotRange -> Full, Filling -> Axis, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

I also have this Piecewise function pwtemp1 (its big, but here could be any simple Piecewise, not defined as a pattern function):

```
pwtemp1=Piecewise[{{Piecewise[{{1.04819277 - E^(-0.03150354*(-1.5 + t)), 
         Inequality[0, LessEqual, -1.5 + t, Less, 1.5]}, 
       {1.002358723234263 - E^(-0.03150354*(-3. + t)), 
         Inequality[1.5, LessEqual, -1.5 + t, Less, 2.4]}, 
       {1.000757843243746 - E^(-0.03150354*(-3.9 + t)), 
         Inequality[2.4, LessEqual, -1.5 + t, Less, 5.0675]}, 
       {1.0020339850944202 - E^(-0.03150354*(-6.5675 + t)), 
         Inequality[5.0675, LessEqual, -1.5 + t, Less, 
           7.734999999999999]}, {1.002065888640687 - 
           E^(-0.03150354*(-9.235 + t)), 
  Inequality[7.734999999999999, 
           LessEqual, -1.5 + t, Less, 10]}}, 0], 
   Inequality[1.5, LessEqual, t, Less, 3.]}, 
 {Piecewise[{{1.04819277 - E^(-0.03150354*(-0.8999999999999999 + 
                   t)), 
  Inequality[0, LessEqual, -0.8999999999999999 + t, 
           Less, 1.5]}, {1.002358723234263 - 
   E^(-0.03150354*(-2.4 + t)), 
         Inequality[1.5, LessEqual, -0.8999999999999999 + t, Less, 
           2.4]}, {1.000757843243746 - E^(-0.03150354*(-3.3 + t)), 
         Inequality[2.4, LessEqual, -0.8999999999999999 + t, Less, 
           5.0675]}, {1.0020339850944202 - 
           E^(-0.03150354*(-5.967499999999999 + t)), 
         
  Inequality[5.0675, LessEqual, -0.8999999999999999 + t, Less, 
           7.734999999999999]}, {1.002065888640687 - 
           E^(-0.03150354*(-8.635 + t)), 
  Inequality[7.734999999999999, 
           LessEqual, -0.8999999999999999 + t, Less, 10]}}, 0], 
   Inequality[3., LessEqual, t, Less, 10]}}, 0]
```

When I Plot pwtemp1, its OK:

```
Plot[pwtemp1, {t, 0, m}, PlotRange -> Full, Filling -> Axis, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

**NOW**, the core point! **I simple need to calculate the Integral of the multiplication of "pwtemp1" and "pwtemp2"**. Both pwtemp1 and pwtemp2 are somehow in function of "t", however, pwtemp2 is explicity defined as "pwtemp2[t_]:=" in order to make possible the recursive evaluation of FC1 and FC2. pwtemp1 is a Piecewise function, and inside of it, also have the variable "t". But, when I try:

```
NIntegrate[pwtemp1 pwtemp2[t], {t, 0, m}]/m
0.0372106
```

It returns a WRONG value, that represents only the Integral of pwtemp1. To confirm, when I evaluate as below, returns the same result! **WHY?**

```
NIntegrate[pwtemp1, {t, 0, m}]/m
0.0372106
```

And the weird is that when I Plot the same expression that I tried to calculate the Integral, the Plot returns the correct graph. Note that 0.0372106 could not be the Integral result (divided by m=10 to get the Average), as far as visually the Integral result should be less that that.

```
Plot[pwtemp1 pwtemp2[t], {t, 0, m}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 Filling -> Axis, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Comment: Please add values for $m$ and for $f$ to your code.  I am not able to reproduce your first plot when I copy/paste your code into a fresh notebook.

Comment: Similar crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2405917).

Comment: Yes, Rohit, thank you. It is me making the same question in another Forum.

Comment: Thank you LouisB, updated. f=0.6 and m=10;

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `pwtemp2` must be evaluated only when `t` is numeric, since the [`Count`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Count) expressions in the definition of FC1 and FC2 don't work when `t` is not numeric. Your definition:

```
pwtemp2[t_] := Piecewise[
    {
    {PSA^FC1[t], Vscc \[LessSlantEqual] t < 2 Vscc},
    {PSA^FC2[t], 2 Vscc \[LessSlantEqual] t < m}
    }
]
```

With this definition:

```
pwtemp2[t] //InputForm
```

> Piecewise[{{1., Inequality[1.5, LessEqual, t, Less, 3.] ||
> Inequality[3., LessEqual, t, Less, 10]}}, 0]

which is not what you wanted. So, instead do:

```
Clear[pwtemp2]

pwtemp2[t_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[
    {
    {PSA^FC1[t], Vscc \[LessSlantEqual] t < 2 Vscc},
    {PSA^FC2[t], 2 Vscc \[LessSlantEqual] t < m}
    }
]
```

Then:

```
NIntegrate[pwtemp1 pwtemp2[t], {t, 0, m}]/m
NIntegrate[pwtemp1, {t, 0, m}]/m
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in t near {t} = {7.73885}. NIntegrate obtained 0.13804431935748623 `and 0.000049087052203923556` for the integral and error estimates.

> 0.0138044

> 0.0372106

return different values.

Comment: One can get rid of the convergence problem by manually including all the possible discontinuities (e.g., replace `{t, 0, m}` by `Evaluate@ Flatten@{t, Union@ Select[Flatten@N@{0, m, vti, vti + Vscc, vti + f Vscc}, 0 <= # <= m &]}` -- might be a little overkill but yet sufficient)